# Recive The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given when i call phpinfo()

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpstorm

When try to call at `phpinfo()` function, Laravel return me this error:

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

The code is:

```
Route::get('phpinfo', function () {
    return phpinfo();
});
```

The version of Laravel is 5.6

**EDIT:**

When I use

```
Route::get('phpinfo', function () {
    return utf8_encode(phpinfo());
});
```

The page render good but I'm worried that this may give me problems in the future. Is it something punctual with the render of the phpinfo page? Have I touched something in my PhpStorm without wanting to?

Laravel is newly installed and the route pointing to `/` works well and renders the html correctly but I am also worried about this:

[image]

The breadcrumb highlighted in red seems to be rendering strange characters.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: *"The breadcrumb highlighted in red seems to be rendering strange characters."* The font used for rendering that element does not support that character. Must be because you are using Material Theme UI plugin. Anyway -- that should be a `lambda` character that represents the function you are currently in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the message says, the router expects a function that returns a string value, or at least an object that has implemented __toString, so that it can be converted into a string value.

`phpinfo` does not return a string value - the result you *see* is written directly into the output stream, and it *returns* either true or false.

With `return utf8_encode(phpinfo());` you are "fixing" the problem in a sense that the function now has an actual string return value. The phpinfo output is still written to the output stream immediately, but you are now UTF8-encoding its return value `true`, which will implicitly be converted to `1` first, so that eventually the whole thing returns that as a string value. But this will likely leave you with that `1` being output somewhere ...

So you should rather call `phpinfo` first, and then just return an empty string afterwards.

Because `phpinfo` writes directly into the output stream, this could still cause problems later on - so the "clean" solution here would probably be to use *output buffering* to first of all catch the `phpinfo` output, and then return the buffer content.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But this will only happen with phpinfo () or can it happen with other returns later in the project?
This project is in Laravel 5.6 with PHP 7.2 I have been working for 6 months on another project with Laravel 5.5 and php 7.1 and it has never given me this error.

Comment: It will happen in any case were you return a result that's not a string value/object with _toString implementation.

Comment: And how can I fix all this at the project level? With laravel 5.5 this. With laravel 5.5 this does not happen. Would it be better to use laravel 5.5?

Comment: What _is_ there to fix? How often do you really need to use functions that behave this way (direct writing to buffer, none/no string return value)? And if you do need to once in a while, I already mentioned how you can solve it (output buffering.) But the usage of such "debug" functions is not your app's main purpose in the first place, is it? _"Would it be better to use laravel 5.5?"_ - restrictions like this are usually added for good reason ... to prevent you from doing "bad" stuff that earlier versions might have allowed for, but could easily lead into trouble.